# Oracle insert query is throwing exception

Tags: oracle

I am trying to execute the below query

```
insert into IOA_SETTLEMENT (version, CREATEDDATE, UPDATEDDATE, ENTITY_VERSION, SETY_ID, amount, curr_iso_code, part_id_rbsparty, ssin_id_rbsparty, ssin_id_counterparty, swift_ack_detail, SWIFT_TRANSACTION_ID, RESP_SWIFT_SINGLE, RESP_SWIFT_WITH_COVER, RESP_COVER_NOTE, si_type_counterparty, si_type_rbsparty, settlement_method, settlement_date, settlement_sent_date, manually_settled_flag, accounting_date, accounting_sent_date, RULE_ID, req_accounting_flag, stp_flag, part_id_counterparty, WQTY_CODE_CURRENT, ADVI_ID, locked_down_flag, TRANS_ERROR_CODE, VCO_FLAG, DTCC_LOCKED_DOWN_FLAG, DEADLINE_FLAG, INTERNAL_FLAG, CREATED_BY, dispatchdate, CLS_ELIGIBILITY_FLAG, HIGH_LEVEL_PRODUCT, USER_NOTE, overridden_release_time, overridden_cutoff_time, id) values
(0, '2016-11-02 14:23:09', '2016-11-02 14:23:09', 1,3, '-120.0','USD','29657030', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 'STD', 'STD', 'SWIFT', '02 November 2016',
null, 'false', '02 November 2016', null, null, 'true',  'true', '29657030', 'BrokerageDraftSettlementWFQueue', null,'false', null, 'false', 'false', 'false','false', 'bro_auth', '2016-11-02 14:00:00', 'false', null, null, null, null, 220884310)
```

below is the table structure

```
Name                           Null     Type                                                                                                                                                                                          
    ------------------------------ -------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    ID                             NOT NULL NUMBER(32)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    VERSION                        NOT NULL NUMBER(20)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    CREATEDDATE                    NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    UPDATEDDATE                             TIMESTAMP(6)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    SETY_ID                        NOT NULL NUMBER(32)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    AMOUNT                         NOT NULL NUMBER(25,5)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    CURR_ISO_CODE                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(3)                                                                                                                                                                                   
    PART_ID_RBSPARTY               NOT NULL NUMBER(32)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    SSIN_ID_RBSPARTY                        NUMBER(32)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    SI_TYPE_RBSPARTY               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    SSIN_ID_COUNTERPARTY                    NUMBER(32)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    SI_TYPE_COUNTERPARTY           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    PART_ID_COUNTERPARTY           NOT NULL NUMBER(32)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    TEMP_SI_ID_RBSPARTY                     NUMBER(32)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    TEMP_SI_ID_COUNTERPARTY                 NUMBER(32)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    SETTLEMENT_METHOD                       VARCHAR2(20)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    SETTLEMENT_DATE                NOT NULL DATE                                                                                                                                                                                          
    SETTLEMENT_SENT_DATE                    TIMESTAMP(6)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    ACCOUNTING_DATE                         DATE                                                                                                                                                                                          
    ACCOUNTING_SENT_DATE                    DATE                                                                                                                                                                                          
    MANUALLY_SETTLED_FLAG          NOT NULL CHAR(1)                                                                                                                                                                                       
    MANUALLY_ACCOUNTED_FLAG        NOT NULL CHAR(1)                                                                                                                                                                                       
    REQ_ACCOUNTING_FLAG            NOT NULL CHAR(1)                                                                                                                                                                                       
    STP_FLAG                       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)                                                                                                                                                                                   
    RULE_ID                                 NUMBER(32)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    ADVI_ID                                 NUMBER(32)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    WQTY_CODE_CURRENT              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)                                                                                                                                                                                 
    LOCKED_DOWN_FLAG                        CHAR(1)                                                                                                                                                                                       
    TOKEN_OWNER                             VARCHAR2(3)                                                                                                                                                                                   
    TRANS_ERROR_CODE                        VARCHAR2(10)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    VCO_FLAG                       NOT NULL CHAR(1)                                                                                                                                                                                       
    DTCC_LOCKED_DOWN_FLAG          NOT NULL CHAR(1)                                                                                                                                                                                       
    DEADLINE_FLAG                  NOT NULL CHAR(1)                                                                                                                                                                                       
    SWIFT_ACK_DETAIL                        VARCHAR2(1000)                                                                                                                                                                                
    SWIFT_TRANSACTION_ID                    VARCHAR2(20)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    RESP_SWIFT_SINGLE                       VARCHAR2(20)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    RESP_COVER_NOTE                         VARCHAR2(20)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    RESP_SWIFT_WITH_COVER                   VARCHAR2(20)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    INTERNAL_FLAG                  NOT NULL CHAR(1)                                                                                                                                                                                       
    CREATED_BY                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    DISPATCHDATE                            TIMESTAMP(6)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    ENTITY_VERSION                 NOT NULL NUMBER(20)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    CLS_ELIGIBILITY_FLAG           NOT NULL CHAR(1)                                                                                                                                                                                       
    HIGH_LEVEL_PRODUCT                      VARCHAR2(20)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    OVERRIDDEN_RELEASE_TIME                 TIMESTAMP(6)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    OVERRIDDEN_CUTOFF_TIME                  TIMESTAMP(6)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    USER_NOTE                               NUMBER(32)
```

but the above nnsert query is not working giving exception in oracle request you to please advise what went wrong in that above query is there any parameter is wrong that is interms of value with tabe ddl

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: Please don't rely on NLS settings for dates and timestamps (or anything else); you're passing strings for those, and for the amount which should be a number. Which may or may not be causing the first error you're getting, but will cause you problems one day. Use the right data types, and either explicit conversion or appropriate literals.

Answer (score 3):

Put the fields you are trying to insert side-by-side with the table's columns.

You will notice that there are 43 values in the `INSERT` statement, while the table has 47 columns. This gives you a clue about potentially missing mandatory fields.

The missing fields are `TEMP_SI_ID_RBSPARTY`, 
`TEMP_SI_ID_COUNTERPARTY`, `MANUALLY_ACCOUNTED_FLAG` and `TOKEN_OWNER`.

Among the four previously mentioned field, only `MANUALLY_ACCOUNTED_FLAG` is mandatory, since it is marked as `NOT NULL`. Therefore, you must provide a value for this field so that your insertion can work.

Comment: Also OP is inserting `'false'` for column `cls_eligibility_flag` that is actually defined as `CLS_ELIGIBILITY_FLAG           NOT NULL CHAR(1)`. so there are things like that too :)

Comment: Right! OP must not only verify the statement _syntactically_, but also _semantically_. :)